# How do I avoid cursor jump to beginning of the input when clicking near its edges?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I click inside text input there's a region near the edge which will move cursor to the very beginning. This is much more noticeable on the bigger inputs:

[image]

Initially I thought this is caused by inner shadow-root markup which produces `div` that won't take full height:

[image]

But here in the snippet below wider input has `line-height: 56px` and this inner `div` get's stretched to 56px as well as `input` itself, but that doesnt help with clicks:

[image]

Why does this happen and how do I avoid cursor jumps to the very beginning?

I could use `input.selectionStart` / `input.selectionEnd` to set position via JS, but maybe there are more native and easy ways?

```css
input:nth-child(2) {
  height: 56px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 56px;
}
```

```html
<input value="Default input" />
<input value="Bigger input" />
```

Comment: This is basic browser usability and probably something I wouldn't want to change. However, you could wrap your `<input />` in a `span` or `div` and apply a border to this to give the illusion of being the input box. Even play with the padding, etc. Then set the line height of your actual input to the minimum needed. There are some caveats with this in regards to how this will look when using auto form fills and other browser extensions that work with forms.

Comment: @ourmaninamsterdam is right. Its something that browser provides out of the box, surely you can do some magic with javascript to force the behaviour to the way you want, but ask yourself is it actually needed and will that be a use case for the user?

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest such a solution, but this solution is not ideal.

```js
let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

inputs.forEach(function(inp){
  inp.onclick = function(){
  
  if (inp.selectionStart == '0') {
      inp.selectionStart = pos_caret;
  }

  if ( document.selection ) {
     let sel = document.selection.createRange();
         sel.moveStart('character', -inp.value.length);
            pos_caret = sel.text.length;
         } else if (inp.selectionStart || inp.selectionStart == '0') {
            pos_caret = inp.selectionStart;
         }      
  }
});
```

```css
input:nth-child(2) {
  height: 56px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 56px;
}
```

```html
<input value="Default input" />
<input value="Bigger input" />
```